# How do I add a custom matrix to the matrix transformation stack in Python Processing?

Tags: python, matrix, processing

I am working with Python Processing. I have a custom matrix that I'd like to add to the current matrix transformation stack without having to first bother to factor the matrix into rotateX() rotateY() etc.

How can I specify my own matrix and apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to answer questions like this is to look in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/applyMatrix_.html).

Sounds like you're looking for the `applyMatrix()` function:

> ```
> size(100, 100, P3D);
> noFill();
> translate(50, 50, 0);
> rotateY(PI/6); 
> stroke(153);
> box(35);
> // Set rotation angles
> float ct = cos(PI/9.0);
> float st = sin(PI/9.0);          
> // Matrix for rotation around the Y axis
> applyMatrix(  ct, 0.0,  st,  0.0,
>              0.0, 1.0, 0.0,  0.0,
>              -st, 0.0,  ct,  0.0,
>              0.0, 0.0, 0.0,  1.0);  
> stroke(255);
> box(50);
> ```
>
> [image: transformed cube]
> <sub>(source: [processing.org](https://processing.org/reference/images/applyMatrix_.png))</sub>

> Multiplies the current matrix by the one specified through the
> parameters. This is very slow because it will try to calculate the
> inverse of the transform, so avoid it whenever possible. The
> equivalent function in OpenGL is glMultMatrix().

The equivalent Processing.py reference is [here](https://py.processing.org/reference/applyMatrix.html).

Comment: There is an alternate method that seems to be not referenced. You can define a custom matrix globally `PMatrix mat = new PMatrix2D(2, 0, 200, 0, 2, 200)` (Scale by 2 and translate by 200, 200). Then you can just apply it using `setMatrix(mat)` in `draw()`. I'm unaware of the pros and cons using this method compared to `applyMatrix`, as I can't find any info on it. It is briefly mentioned amongst the long list of methods in processing-javadocs.